# How to remove the red line for a react button containing a js link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a button in react which will redirect users to something else using a javascript href link which works, but the words in the button keep a red line under them

I've already tried the basic way of `style="text-decoration:none"` that gets used for text to not get the underline, but for this button that only makes my page fail loading with a blank screen

my code looks about like this

  
     Go to link

I expect my button and page to load properly with no underline under the button but so far my attempts only break the page

Comment: It doesn't look like you were able to post your code, it is just text that says "Go to link." Can you edit your post with a link to your source code?

Comment: Post your code also.

Comment: Can we have the image of the "red line"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}
```

Comment: Why should he do that?

Comment: @Rob because this is react, very silly mistake from me

Comment: That still doesn't explain how it answers the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer